# How to running a custom function with Groupby and Apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a custom function on a Pandas dataframe, so that I runs for each name and gives me output, then runs on a similar group of names. But I'm stuck and can't seem to figure out how to finish up here.

```
INPUT:
          NAME   STEPS
    0   Andrew    PASS
    1   Andrew    PASS
    2   Andrew    PASS
    3   Sam       PASS
    4   Sam       PASS
```

```py
def my_function(df):
    # consecutive passes and strikes
    consecutive_passes = 0
    consecutive_passes_list = []

    points = 0
    points_list = []

    running_count = 0
    running_count_list = []

    fails = 0

    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.STEPS[i] == "PASS":
            consecutive_passes += 1
            if consecutive_passes >= 11:
                points = 2
                consecutive_passes_list.append(consecutive_passes)
                points_list.append(strikes)
    #             print("PASS", consecutive_passes, points)
            else:
                consecutive_passes_list.append(consecutive_passes)
                points_list.append(points)
    #             print("PASS", consecutive_passes, points)

        if df.STEPS[i] == "FAIL":
            consecutive_passes = 0
            fails += 1
            points -= 1
            if points == -1:
                points = 0
                consecutive_passes_list.append(consecutive_passes)
                points_list.append(points)
    #             print("FAIL", consecutive_passes, points)
            else:
                consecutive_passes_list.append(consecutive_passes)
                points_list.append(points)
    #             print("FAIL", consecutive_passes, points)
    
    df["CONSECUTIVE_PASSES"] = consecutive_passes_list
    df["POINTS"] = points_list
    
    # inspection rate
    inspection_rate = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.POINTS[i] == 0:
            inspection_rate.append(low_risk[df.CONSECUTIVE_PASSES[i]])
        if df.POINTS[i] == 2:
            ir = low_risk[df.CONSECUTIVE_PASSES[i]]
            inspection_rate.append(ir)
        if df.POINTS[i] == 1:
            inspection_rate.append(ir)
    
    df["INSPECTION_RATE"] = inspection_rate
    
    return df.tail()
```

Really I need help. Figuring out how to run the function for each name and returning the last row of the dataframe. IF someone could help me cross the finish line that would be nice. Thanks!!!'

```
ERROR UPDATE:

<ipython-input-74-41b5a1cc100d>:36: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["CONSECUTIVE_PASSES"] = consecutive_passes_list
<ipython-input-74-41b5a1cc100d>:37: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["STRIKES"] = strikes_list
```

Comment: Return the values that you are trying to insert into your df instead of putting them in your df.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function does what it should you can run it like this to get what you want.

```
results = {}
for name in df.NAME.unique():
     results[name] = my_function(df[df["NAME"]==name])
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following error when I run it though.

Comment: instead of  `df["CONSECUTIVE_PASSES"] = consecutive_passes_list` just return consecutive_passes_list and likewise for Points and inspection rate. You can return 3 values it will just be a tuple.